# Split cells in datagridview vb.NET. Is that possible?

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, split, cell

I need to represent different 4 (max, maybe 2 or 3) colors to the user in datagridview control @ VB.NET. An example cell would be:

---

```
---------------
| Blue | Red  |
---------------    <<<- A Cell
| Gray | Blue |
---------------
```

---

### So,

i need to split a cell to different size or counts. I know merging cells is possible, is opposite-merge possible? Or anybody have any idea for this problem?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can think of three solutions:

---

Have extra columns and rows so you can merge them into any pattern you'd expect.

---

Handle the `DataGridView.RowPrePaint` event.  Record the row index for use in the following event.

Handle the `DataGridView.CellPainting` event.  You can get the column index, cell bounds, and graphics handler from the event args (`e`).  Call `e.Graphics.FillRectange()`

---

Create a custom class inheriting from `System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCell`.  Add properties to define the cell splitting and colours.  Write your custom painting in the Paint event.  Populate the DataGridView with these cell types.